# DKIM *seems* to be used as an open relay. Is this possible?

Tags: postfix, opendkim, relay

I'm running postfix with opendkim. <strike>*My opendkim milter is running on port 10029.*</strike>
**CORRECTION**: My opendkim milter is running on a unix socket, and there is a DKIM content filter set up on port 10029.

Just today, I started seeing messages like this appearing in my postfix log ...

```
2023.11.01 21:29:40 hippo postfix/smtp[29756]: EBBA428F83B: to=<southboundbecca@yahoo.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10029, delay=0.94, delays=0.78/0.01/0.04/0.11, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as B71ED28F83C)
```

It appears that some people have figured out how to use my opendkim milter as an open relay. Or am I somehow misinterpreting this log message?

My postfix server itself is not an open relay, and smtp can only be initiated via authentication.

If I am correct in guessing that opendkim is being used as an open relay, is this a known problem? Or if I'm totally misunderstanding what's going on, can anyone help me understand what's actually happening with those seemingly relayed messages?

Thank you very much.

**UPDATE**: Could it be that someone discovered that 10029 is an open port, and that it's possible to misuse DKIM's listening port in order to relay emails?

If so, do I simply need to do the following in order to only enable port 10029 access from localhost? ...

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 10029 -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 10029 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Show a configuration. How can we tell by just a single log line? It can be, of course, and that's why it's usually hooked as a *MIlter*, not as SMTP pass-through, and is listening on an unix socket.

Comment: Please [add](https://serverfault.com/posts/1147045/edit) more log context, and [your configuration](https://serverfault.com/tags/postfix/info).

Comment: I already stated that it's hooked as a milter, even in the first sentence of my question text. I'll change it to a unix socket. That will probably fix this.  My question is whether or not it *can* be used as a pass-through, and it's been stated here now that it indeed can be. I will definitely post the entire config later today when I'm back home, even though it seems redundant at this point, given that I now know what seems to be occurring and how to fix it (i.e., can be used as a pass-through, and unix socket instead of TCP socket).

Comment: My supposition is correct, but I found a more basic cause for the problem. I posted the fix in my Answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the iptables fix indeed corrected my problem, although I had originally posted the commands in the wrong order. Should be this way ...

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 10029 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 10029 -j DROP
```

But the more basic problem that I needed solve was as follows:

Long ago I switched from `DKIMproxy` to `opendkim`.

My milter setup is already properly using a unix socket for `opendkim` connectivity, but there was some old, left-over code in `master.cf` that references `DKIMproxy` that I forgot to delete, as follows:

```
smtp.name-of-my-host.net:submission inet n       -       y       -       MAXPROC       smtpd
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_etrn_restrictions=reject
  -o receive_override_options=no_address_mappings
  -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=CONNLIMIT
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
######## Code to delete starts here ########
  -o content_filter=dksign:[127.0.0.1]:10029
# dkim (listening on 10029, sends to 10030)
dksign    unix  -       -       n       -       5       smtp
  -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
  -o smtp_discard_ehlo_keywords=8bitmime,starttls
127.0.0.1:10030 inet  n  -      y       -       10      smtpd
  -o content_filter=
  -o receive_override_options=no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_header_body_checks
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
  -o smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts=127.0.0.0/8
######## End of code to delete ########
```

All I needed to do was delete everything from the `-o content_filter=dksign:[127.0.0.1]:10029` line to the end of the listed code block, and the problem went away.

And, of course, after that, I don't need the `iptables` commands any more.

The reason I never saw this problem until now is probably that someone must have recently discovered the open 10029 port that had been sitting around since a long time ago.